# Collection mapping is broken after upgrade to Automapper 3.*, when collection is lazily initialized

Tags: c#, automapper

Consider these classes:

```
class Master
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Detail> Details
    {
        get
        {
            return details ?? (details = new ObservableCollection<Detail>());
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Detail> details;
}

class Detail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MasterId { get; set; }
}
```

...and some code, which uses Automapper version 3.0 or higher:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<Master, Master>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Detail, Detail>();
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        var original = new Master
        {
            Id = 1,
            Details = 
            {
                new Detail { Id = 1, MasterId = 1 },
                new Detail { Id = 2, MasterId = 1 },
                new Detail { Id = 3, MasterId = 1 },
            }
        };

        var copy = Mapper.Map<Master>(original);

        Console.WriteLine(copy.Details.Count); // outputs 0
```

Now, let's change `Master` definition (replace read only, lazily initialized collection property with read-write one):

```
class Master
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Detail> Details { get; set; }
}
```

...and sample code (now we should call collection constructor):

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<Master, Master>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Detail, Detail>();
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        var original = new Master
        {
            Id = 1,
            Details = new ObservableCollection<Detail>
            {
                new Detail { Id = 1, MasterId = 1 },
                new Detail { Id = 2, MasterId = 1 },
                new Detail { Id = 3, MasterId = 1 },
            }
        };

        var copy = Mapper.Map<Master>(original);

        Console.WriteLine(copy.Details.Count); // outputs 3
```

**Before Automapper version 3.0, collection items was copied successfully.**

The questions:

- Is there any official explanation, why this behavior was broken?
- Is there any workaround (except changing collections to read/write properties, manual copying, or downgrade to previous versions of Automapper)?

P.S. I've asked the similar question already, but it wasn't answered and now I can post a code, which is reproducing buggy behavior.

Comment: I'm confused - in the CreateMap calls, are the left-hand and right-hand types the same types?

Comment: Yes, they are. In real application mapper being used for cloning purposes.